# Upload multiple files and post vars with fsockopen

Tags: php, fsockopen

I want both to send multiple files and post vars in a http request with fsockopen..

Have come up with this code, but I don't know how to send the post vars with the files!? Have uncommented the line where the post data query is build, but don't know how to put it in the request!? :(

## index.php

```
$post_vars = [
    'label' => 'description of the upload'
];

$files = [
    'upload_file_1.txt',
    'upload_file_2.txt'
];

try{
    $boundary = sha1(1);
    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $body = '';

    foreach($files as $file){
        $finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mimetype = $finfo->file($file);

        $file_contents = quoted_printable_encode(file_get_contents($file));

        $body .= '--'.$boundary.$crlf
            .'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="'.basename($file).'"'.$crlf
            .'Content-Type: '.$mimetype.$crlf
            .'Content-Length: '.strlen($file_contents).$crlf
            .'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'.$crlf.$crlf
            .$file_contents.$crlf;
    }

    $body .= '--'.$boundary.'--';

    //$post_data = http_build_query($post_vars);

    $response = '';
    if($fp = fsockopen('localhost', 80, $errno, $errstr, 20)){
        $write = "POST /api_test/filepost/post.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            ."Host: localhost\r\n"
            ."Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary."\r\n"
            ."Content-Length: ".strlen($body)."\r\n"
            ."Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"
            .$body;
        fwrite($fp, $write);

        echo "-------------------- REQUEST START --------------------\n".$write."\n-------------------- REQUEST END --------------------\n\n\n";

        while($line = fgets($fp)){
            if($line !== false){
                $response .= $line;
            }
        }

        fclose($fp);

        echo "-------------------- RESPONSE START --------------------\n".$response."\n-------------------- RESPONSE END --------------------\n\n";
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("$errstr ($errno)");
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

## post.php

```
echo "get\n";
print_r($_GET);

echo "post\n";
print_r($_POST);

echo "files\n";
print_r($_FILES);
```

## output

```
-------------------- REQUEST START --------------------
POST /api_test/filepost/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Length: 540
Connection: Close

--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="upload_file_1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

contents of file 1
--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="upload_file_2.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

contents of file 2
--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab--
-------------------- REQUEST END --------------------


-------------------- RESPONSE START --------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 08:46:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3
Content-Length: 803
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

get
Array
(
)
post
Array
(
)
files
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => upload_file_1.txt
                    [1] => upload_file_2.txt
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                    [1] => text/plain
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1827.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1828.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18
                    [1] => 18
                )

        )

)

-------------------- RESPONSE END --------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

## index.php

```
$post_vars = [
    'label' => 'description of the upload'
];

$files = [
    'upload_file_1.txt',
    'upload_file_2.txt'
];

try{
    $boundary = sha1(1);
    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $body = '';

    foreach($post_vars as $key => $value){
        $body .= '--'.$boundary.$crlf
            .'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'.$key.'"'.$crlf
            .'Content-Length: '.strlen($value).$crlf.$crlf
            .$value.$crlf;
    }

    foreach($files as $file){
        $finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mimetype = $finfo->file($file);

        $file_contents = quoted_printable_encode(file_get_contents($file));

        $body .= '--'.$boundary.$crlf
            .'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="'.basename($file).'"'.$crlf
            .'Content-Type: '.$mimetype.$crlf
            .'Content-Length: '.strlen($file_contents).$crlf
            .'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'.$crlf.$crlf
            .$file_contents.$crlf;
    }

    $body .= '--'.$boundary.'--';

    //$post_data = http_build_query($post_vars);

    $response = '';
    if($fp = fsockopen('localhost', 80, $errno, $errstr, 20)){
        $write = "POST /api_test/filepost/post.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            ."Host: localhost\r\n"
            ."Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary."\r\n"
            ."Content-Length: ".strlen($body)."\r\n"
            ."Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"
            .$body;
        fwrite($fp, $write);

        echo "-------------------- REQUEST START --------------------\n".$write."\n-------------------- REQUEST END --------------------\n\n\n";

        while($line = fgets($fp)){
            if($line !== false){
                $response .= $line;
            }
        }

        fclose($fp);

        echo "-------------------- RESPONSE START --------------------\n".$response."\n-------------------- RESPONSE END --------------------\n\n";
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("$errstr ($errno)");
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

## post.php

```
echo "get\n";
print_r($_GET);

echo "post\n";
print_r($_POST);

echo "files\n";
print_r($_FILES);
```

## output

```
-------------------- REQUEST START --------------------
POST /api_test/filepost/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Length: 679
Connection: Close

--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="label"
Content-Length: 25

description of the upload
--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="upload_file_1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

contents of file 1
--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="upload_file_2.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

contents of file 2
--356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab--
-------------------- REQUEST END --------------------


-------------------- RESPONSE START --------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 09:07:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3
Content-Length: 844
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

get
Array
(
)
post
Array
(
    [label] => description of the upload
)
files
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => upload_file_1.txt
                    [1] => upload_file_2.txt
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                    [1] => text/plain
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE35D.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE35E.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18
                    [1] => 18
                )

        )

)

-------------------- RESPONSE END --------------------
```

Comment: Why do you have Content-Type field twice per block?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

`.$file_contents.$crlf.$crlf;` -> `.$file_contents.$crlf;`